# How to Append google auto complete inside modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to add **[Google autocomplete places](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) inside modal popup**, but the issue I am facing is that it appends to body instead of modal, is there any way we can append it inside modal?
[`Codepen Example`](https://codepen.io/shoaibmalik/pen/wvBeXaG)

[image]

Reason: when modal opens, it scrolls set to hidden same as Bootstrap modal, and when "Auto Complete" is append to body it changes it's position while scrolling

kindly see below:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this problem, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you need to show the code, if you need help

Comment: Hi Vipul, I have added a reference to original google places as well as codepen example, if you search something in searchbox and than scroll after getting result, you will see that popover displaced.

-thanks for your help

Comment: yes i can see the issue, the search lister gets appended to the HTML body, this must be its default behavior, may be can fix this by using JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google autocomplete gets appended to the ***HTML Body*** tag and from there it traces the position of the specified input serach box.

You can add a scroll event listener on the ***#myModal*** element and then trace the position of the input ***#pac-input***.

Add the following code after the ***initAutocomplete*** function.

```
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.onscroll = function(e) {
    const pacContainer = document.querySelector(".pac-container.pac-logo");
    let top = window.scrollY + document.getElementById("pac-input").getBoundingClientRect().top;
    pacContainer.style.top = `${top + 25}px`;
}
```

here on scroll of the ***#myModal*** HTML element, its calulating the top position of ***#pac-input*** and adding 25px (Assumed height of input) to the ***google autocomplete div***.

Comment: thanks Vipul, this method of your works, I have to tweak it a little according to my needs.